# Pourquoi faut-il utiliser "ressortir" au lieu de "sortir" dans cette phrase ?

Tags: usage, verbes, préfixes

> Cela augmente vos chances de **ressortir** vivants du sous-marin.

Ce sera **la première fois** qu'ils mettront les pieds dans le sous-marin et qu'ils s'en sortiront (s'ils y parviendront). Pourquoi donc est-ce qu'il emploie plutôt le verbe "ressortir" qui signifie le fait de sortir **de nouveau** ?

Comment: je dirais que ressortir  implique un risque (réel, imaginaire, pour sa sécurité, financier, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ressortir** au sens propre peut vouloir dire :

**Sortir à nouveau** [1.a α)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/ressortir)

> Je suis arrivé à 14 heures chez moi et je suis ressorti dix minutes plus tard pour faire des courses.

**Sortir après être entré** [1.a β)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/ressortir)

> Je suis entré dans le nouveau supermarché pour faire mes courses mais il y faisait tellement froid que j'en suis vite ressorti.

Donc dans l'exemple donné les deux, *sortir* et *ressortir*, sont possibles sans aucune différence de sens. Il est d'ailleurs probable qu'avant de se lancer pour de vrai dans un sous-marin on fasse des essais, et donc que peut-être ceux qui risquent leur vie y ont déjà séjourné auparavant.

Comment: Je ne crois pas qu'il y aie vraiment un sens "de nouveau" dans le cas de *ressortir* (et de presque tout cette famille de verbes, en fait), puisque par définition on ne peut sortir sans être d'abord entré. Pour être exact, il m'apparaît très difficile de construire une phrase qui emploierait ce sens sans que le sens de *après être entré* ne soit possible et vienne la parasiter. De fait, si le sens "à nouveau" est réellement et uniquement désiré, on trouvera plutôt une construction du genre *sortir à nouveau*.

Comment: @Laure: J'y vois bien plus clair maintenant ! À propos, je m'interroge sur la différence entre « Je ne **trouve** pas mes lunettes. » et « Je ne **retrouve** pas mes lunettes. ». Est-ce qu'on utilise le premier quand on les a égarées chez soi, alors que le second est plutôt pour quand on l'a fait dans un grand espace, par exemple dans un aéroport, ou pendant qu'on se promène ? Qu'en penses-tu ? S'il vaut mieux poser cette question sur un nouveau fil, je le ferai. Merci.

Comment: @Laure: I've just opened a new thread, after all. Merci.

Comment: @LUNA Il n'y a aucune différence entre *je ne trouve pas mes lunettes* et *je ne retrouve pas mes lunettes*.  On emploie trouver pour quelque chose qu'on n'a jamais vu auparavant. C'est bien expliqué [ici](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4246).